# Checking multiple prices, increase total price label

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I'm attempting to add up the total price on my website whenever a user clicks on a checkbox - using some jQuery, but only recieving $NaN when I add up the results. The alert box near the end of my script is showing very weird results as well (leading 0s, I'm not sure why)

Here's my current code:

```
$("#AdditionalOffers").bind("click", "input:checkbox", function () {
                    var $items = $("#AdditionalOffers").find("input:checkbox:checked");
                    var $total = $("#totalPrice");
                    var cur_total = 0;

                    $items.each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var target = $("span[class='" + $this.attr("id") + "']");
                        var item_value = +target.text()

                        cur_total += item_value;
                        alert(cur_total);
                    });

                    $total.html("$" + cur_total);
                });
```

Because I'm using .NET, my markup looks like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" CssClass="label-for-check" Text="Lease/Sales Consultation" runat="server" /> <span class="CheckBox7">75</span> <br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" CssClass="label-for-check" Text="Lease Review Advisor" runat="server" /> <span class="CheckBox1">50</span> <br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" CssClass="label-for-check" Text="Starter Package" runat="server" /> <span class="CheckBox2">25</span> <br />
```

I feel like there is a silly reason this isn't working. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ue2mr/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you're using ASP.NET, so the IDs are dynamically generated and `$this.attr("id")` returns a different value than the span class in

```
var target = $("span[class='" + $this.attr("id") + "']");
```

For example, when you look for a span with class `CheckBox7`, but `$this.attr("id")` returns something like `{prefix}CheckBox7`.

**Solution 1:** just replace that line with:

```
var target = $this.next();
```

**Solution 2:**

In case you need to find by class, use another attribute other than id. Like this in code-behind:

```
CheckBox7.Attributes["myspanclass"] = "CheckBox7";
CheckBox1.Attributes["myspanclass"] = "CheckBox1";
CheckBox2.Attributes["myspanclass"] = "CheckBox2";
```

And replace that line with:

```
 var target = $("span[class='" + $this.attr("myspanclass") + "']");
```